# Error when defining a 2D array of chars

Tags: c

I'm trying to define an array of type `char`

```
char data[][]
```

I want to use it to store some data from another array using `strcpy()`

The problem is I don't know exactly what is the length and I can't specify the length in the array, and I'm getting this error:

`Error array type has incomplete element type`

Here's the full code:

```
int bit_to_ascii(const char core[], char data[])
{
      char char_data2[][];

      strcpy(char_data2, core);
      len1 = strlen(char_data2);

}
```

Comment: if you don't know size in advance, you have to declare it as `char **data`, and then allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: Using a two dimensional array here makes not much sense to me. Do you mean something like `strcpy(char_data2[0], core)` ? How do you thinke the compiler or runtime syould be able to guess where you want `char_data2[0]` to end? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either declare it with maximum size possible and acceptable for your case, or use [`malloc(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/malloc.3.html) to ask the runtime to dynamically allocate exact amount of memory for you (then release that memory with [`free(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/malloc.3.html) when done).

Comment: Oh, thanks God someone else prefers kernel.org too. Most people  take first random link from Google which happens to be a silly "die" site. +100500